# Ubuntu One File Sync problem - ssl handshake error

Tags: ubuntu-one

Ubuntu One file sync isn't working for me for 11.04.  It is continuously attempting to sync a small file with no luck.  From `syncdaemon.log`:

```
2011-08-25 21:51:14,263 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Main - NOTE - Local rescan finished!
2011-08-25 21:51:14,263 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Main - INFO - hash queue empty. We are ready!
2011-08-25 21:51:14,288 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection started to host fs-1.ubuntuone.com, port 443.
2011-08-25 21:51:14,473 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection made.
2011-08-25 21:51:14,474 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection made.
2011-08-25 21:51:35,639 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection lost, reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake failure')]
].
2011-08-25 21:51:35,639 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - WARNING - Client mismatch while processing the request 'protocol_version', client (<ubuntuone.syncdaemon.action_queue.ActionQueueProtocol instance at 0x29308c0>) is not self.client (None).
2011-08-25 21:51:35,640 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - WARNING - Connection lost: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake failure')]
2011-08-25 21:51:47,442 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.DBus - INFO - connect was requested. Are we autoconnecting? False.
2011-08-25 21:51:48,177 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.DBus - INFO - 'CredentialsFound': callbacking with credentials.
2011-08-25 21:51:48,178 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.DBus - INFO - connect: credential request was successful, pushing SYS_USER_CONNECT.
2011-08-25 21:51:48,200 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection started to host fs-1.ubuntuone.com, port 443.
2011-08-25 21:51:48,382 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection made.
2011-08-25 21:51:48,382 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection made.
2011-08-25 21:52:09,547 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection lost, reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_READ_BYTES', 'ssl handshake failure')]
].
2011-08-25 21:52:09,730 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.HQ - INFO - HashQueue: _hasher stopped
2011-08-25 21:52:09,730 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.tritcask - INFO - shutting down...
2011-08-25 21:52:09,740 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.DBus - INFO - Shuttingdown DBusInterface!
2011-08-25 21:52:09,747 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - The request 'protocol_version' failed with the error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_READ_BYTES', 'ssl handshake failure')] and was handled with the event: SYS_UNKNOWN_ERROR
2011-08-25 21:52:09,748 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - WARNING - Connection lost: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_READ_BYTES', 'ssl handshake failure')]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Sorry for the inconvenience. We are experiencing a temporary disruption in service. Our engineers are working to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Any updates on this?  I'm a paying customer and would love to depend on the service, but it's never been stable enough to do so.  Here's hoping you get there at some point.

Comment: Yes this should be resolved. To get the best results from Ubuntu One I recommend updating to the newest version of Ubuntu if possible. Older versions of Ubuntu One in for example Ubuntu 10.04 do not have all the improvements of the newer versions. We’re going to be moving as many of these improvements to the client in 10.04 and older clients. It’s taking us a while to do this since the improvements are often significant changes and require a lot of testing to ensure we don’t break existing functionality.